# Adobe alchemy and dllimport

Tags: dll, actionscript, dllimport, swc, alchemy

Is it possible to connect c++ dll to .c file (with dllimport or something else) and convert it to .swc with adobe alchemy? If it does - how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is like asking "can I use a dll on mac os x"?

A dll is platform-specific (windows) machine code. Alchemy is a C/C++ compiler for Flash.  They don't mix- all your code must be compiled with Alchemy.

For more info see the Alchemy [FAQ](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Alchemy%3aFAQ).

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on the desktop (AIR) you can execute DLLs with the NativeProcess. That might be as close as you can get.

Comment: You can't execute DLLs directly with NativeProcess.  However, you could write an executable that uses the DLLs and invoke that via NativeProcess.  Or I suppose you could use [rundll](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164787).  Of course, executing any native code will be platform-specific.  These DLLs won't be usable on other platforms (e.g., Mac OS X).

Comment: Yes, that's true. DLLs won't be cross platform. They'll need some sort of wrapper to work from NativeProcess.